Pandas Online Usage Performance Issues
During the training phase, we use DataFrame for data processing. To ensure that the feature processing functions are consistent between online prediction and training, we also convert data to DataFrame format during online prediction to reuse the feature processing functions from training. However, we have found that DataFrame processing performance is quite poor.
For example, converting a 1*300 dictionary to a DataFrame takes about 7 milliseconds.
def feature_process(data, dense_features):
    # DataFrame assignments are also very time-consuming.
    data.loc[:, dense_features] = self.mms.transform(data.loc[:, dense_features].values)

t = time.time()
data = pd.DataFrame(feature_dict) # feature_dict has 1 row and 300 columns, like this {k1:[1], k2:[1], ... k300:[1]}
print("dataframe", (time.time()-t)*1000) # it cost 7ms

feature_process(data, dense_features) #dense_features is a list which has 150 feature names


Is there a better method that ensures the feature processing functions can be shared between training and online prediction while also improving online processing performance?

Your question is too vague. It's not really possible to comment on performance without a well crafted example and precise specification of the potential efficiency issues and expected improvements.

Sorry, I have added a simple example. Currently, it seems that DataFrame assignments and slicing operations are both very time-consuming.

Hello zhcn! Where does the self. in self.mms.transform(...) comes from? self. should be called from within a class. As of now, self does nothing. Please read (minimal reproducible example)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example]. Answering questions is time intensive, please do make sure your examples run as is, with package import included.

You may convert to a lighter data structure for online prediction, and use DataFrames only for training:
# Training.
def feature_process(data, dense_features):
    if isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame):
        data.loc[:, dense_features] = self.mms.transform(
            data.loc[:, dense_features].values)
    else:
        data[:, dense_features_indices] = self.mms.transform(
            data[:, dense_features_indices])

# Online Prediction.
data = np.array(list(feature_dict.values())).reshape(1, -1)


In that case, how can we ensure that the processing functions are consistent between training and online prediction?

To ensure that feature processing functions can be shared between training and online prediction, would it be better to use NumPy structures during training instead of DataFrame?

Using numpy for both training and prediction can help ensure consistency in the processing functions. If the data is homogeneous (e.g. all floats or integers) I see no reason to use only numpy, since it’s built for performance, and the code would be simpler if both the training and the prediction use the same data structure

Hello AmitG. Whenever you post code to help on StackOverflow, do try to ensure that it runs. self only works while within a class, and there are no classes in your example. Kind regards
